# soql query causing internal server error

Tags: apex, soql

In the developer console query editor, if I enter the query

```
select lastmodifiedDate from foo__c order by lastmodifiedDate desc limit 1
```

it runs fine. But the moment I try do that same query inside of a controller, I get an Internal Server Error. Debug logs show

```
14:44:11.956 (103956172471)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[31]|Aggregations:0|select lastmodifiedDate from foo__c order by lastmodifiedDate desc limit 1
14:46:15.080 (227080647980)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
14:46:15.080 (227080675619)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
14:46:15.080 (227080675619)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 4 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 57 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 100 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

As you can see from the log above, it says the soql query takes over 2 minutes before returning the error. Why is my query failing inside a controller?

Comment: what i am guessing because of your heep size exceed

Comment: do soql queries have a hidden heap size limit?

Comment: looks like it is not a code level error. Try after sometimes may be this will resolved.

Comment: is your query dynamic means you are using database.query() or Database.getQueryLocator() ?

Comment: I'm doing it in a database.query()

Comment: Is it intermediate issue or it shows error every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its performance issue. The query is running super slow. There are multiple options to optimize this query.

1) use SystemModStamp : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/force-com-soql-performance-tips-systemmodstamp-vs-lastmodifieddate-2.html

2) Make query more selective by adding some criteria . i.e. where SystemModStamp > THIS_MOnths  : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/12/force-com-query-optimizer-secrets-you-can-use-today.html

3) Store the timestamp when you update your record.

Comment: In addition to these suggestions, I've found that using the ajax toolkit to do the query is more performant, even though it should have the same governor limits.